# Erro ao executar relatório principal - Jasper Studio

Tags: jasper-reports, drive

Estou gerando um relatório no Jasper Studio, onde o relatório principal possui **N** sub relatórios, sendo que um desses relatórios possui uma conexão com um Database diferente do relatório principal.
Quando eu executo o relatório principal no Jasper Studio a primeira vez eu recebo o seguinte erro:

`Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.226:5432/BancoDados
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at gerenciamentoContratosTI_Master_1527160426610_582447.evaluate
(gerenciamentoContratosTI_Master_1527160426610_582447:241)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:250)`

Porém se eu vou nesse sub relatório e executo ele sozinho (Que funciona normalmente) e depois executo novamente o relatório principal funciona normalmente, alguém sabe o que pode estar causando isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outra coisa que notei é que as vezes se ocorre esse erro e eu tento executar novamente o mesmo relatório sem alterar nada o erro não ocorre novamente, porém quando estou tentando gerar o relatório fora do Jasper studio o erro sempre ocorre mesmo executando mais de uma vez.

**CÓDIGO DO RELATÓRIO**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version last-->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="gerenciamentoContratosTI_Master" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="31b1aa49-0fa2-4acf-9b60-510e34a327f8">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="conexaoMySQL"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <parameter name="empresaInicial" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="dataInicial" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="dataFinal" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="conteudoPrincipal" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\romualdo\\JaspersoftWorkspace\\MyReports\\RelatoriosFinal\\resumoTrimestral.jasper"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="tempoTotal" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\romualdo\\JaspersoftWorkspace\\MyReports\\RelatoriosFinal\\tempoTotalTrimestre.jasper"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="cabecalho" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\romualdo\\JaspersoftWorkspace\\MyReports\\RelatoriosFinal\\dadosContratosTI.jasper"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="empresaFinal" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="chamados" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\romualdo\\JaspersoftWorkspace\\MyReports\\RelatoriosFinal\\Chamados.jasper"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="resumoMensal" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\romualdo\\JaspersoftWorkspace\\MyReports\\RelatoriosFinal\\resumoMensal.jasper"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="valorTotalRequisicoes" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\romualdo\\JaspersoftWorkspace\\MyReports\\RelatoriosFinal\\valorTotalRequisicoes.jasper"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[SELECT 
    otrs.ticket.customer_id as EMPRESA,
    (case when day(sysdate()) < 10 then MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(Month(now()) -1,'%m')) else
    MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(Month(now()),'%m')) end) as mes
FROM 
    otrs.ticket,
    otrs.users,
    otrs.ticket_type,
    otrs.ticket_state,
    otrs.service,
    otrs.time_accounting,
   otrs.customer_company cc2
WHERE
    cc2.valid_id = 1 and
    cc2.customer_id = otrs.ticket.customer_id and
    otrs.ticket.id = otrs.time_accounting.ticket_id and
    otrs.ticket.user_id = otrs.users.id and
    otrs.ticket.type_id = otrs.ticket_type.id and
    otrs.ticket.ticket_state_id = otrs.ticket_state.id and
    otrs.ticket.service_id = otrs.service.id and
    /*otrs.ticket.change_time between '2018-02-01' and '2018-04-30' and*/
    otrs.time_accounting.change_time between $P!{dataInicial} and $P!{dataFinal} and
    otrs.ticket.customer_id between $P{empresaInicial} and $P{empresaFinal} and
    otrs.ticket_type.name = 'Contrato PCH'
group by 
    EMPRESA
order by 
    EMPRESA]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="EMPRESA" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="mes" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <variable name="valorTotalRelatorio" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Empresa" calculation="System"/>
    <variable name="valorHoraTrimestralRelatorio" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Empresa" calculation="System"/>
    <variable name="multiplicadorServidorRelatorio" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Empresa" calculation="System"/>
    <variable name="valorHoraAdicionalRelatorio" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Empresa" calculation="System"/>
    <variable name="horasContratadasRelatorio" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Empresa" calculation="System"/>
    <variable name="quantidadeChamados" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="None" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="Empresa" calculation="Count"/>
    <variable name="valorMensalRelatorio" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Empresa" calculation="System"/>
    <variable name="arrayChamadosRelatorio" class="java.lang.String" resetType="Group" resetGroup="Empresa" calculation="System"/>
    <variable name="valorTotalRequisicoesRelatorio" class="java.lang.Double" calculation="System"/>
    <group name="Empresa">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{EMPRESA}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="181">
                <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                <rectangle>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="71" width="802" height="20" forecolor="#4A8FC7" backcolor="#4A8FC7" uuid="7dff156d-4f09-428e-be15-6c4df13d2f9f">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                </rectangle>
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement x="10" y="95" width="670" height="76" uuid="75b469b7-ec70-423b-bf4e-f0b5e06284c1">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <subreportParameter name="empresaInicial">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{EMPRESA}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="dataFinal">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{dataFinal}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.226:5432/BancoDados","postgres","9ORwi%Iz4Uq9")]]></connectionExpression>
                    <returnValue subreportVariable="valorHoraTrimestralSubRelatorio" toVariable="valorHoraTrimestralRelatorio"/>
                    <returnValue subreportVariable="multiplicadorServidorSubRelatorio" toVariable="multiplicadorServidorRelatorio"/>
                    <returnValue subreportVariable="valorHoraAdicionalSubRelatorio" toVariable="valorHoraAdicionalRelatorio"/>
                    <returnValue subreportVariable="horasContratadasSubRelatorio" toVariable="horasContratadasRelatorio"/>
                    <returnValue subreportVariable="valorMensalSubRelatorio" toVariable="valorMensalRelatorio"/>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{cabecalho}]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="58" y="71" width="398" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="30790453-d6db-499c-9e64-b5c7de8e837f"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding=""/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{EMPRESA}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="1" y="71" width="55" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="f32bbd89-a209-4f81-ab82-0b7c51042316">
                        <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[   CLIENTE:]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <image>
                    <reportElement x="10" y="13" width="121" height="37" uuid="44f92e3c-9af6-4264-bdd3-cfa1edc638f0"/>
                    <imageExpression><![CDATA["http://www.hss.com.br/images/logo_oficial.png"]]></imageExpression>
                </image>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="172" y="11" width="498" height="21" uuid="1ce8eb7c-edca-40b6-bdf8-dcf0022444bf"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="16" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[RELATÓRIO DE GERENCIAMENTO DE CHAMADOS]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="351" y="32" width="100" height="20" uuid="593ccefe-36e5-49cd-8fe4-80ac098c4bd6"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="14"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{mes}.replace("January", "Janeiro").replace("February", "Fevereiro").replace("March", "Março").replace("April", "Abril").replace("May", "Maio").replace("June", "Junho").replace("July", "Julho").replace("August", "Agosto").replace("September", "Setembro").replace("October", "Outubro").replace("November", "Novembro").replace("December", "Dezembro")]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="1">
                <break>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="99" height="1" uuid="90838081-d37e-45bd-b976-39e6c76a3dc0"/>
                </break>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="80">
            <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="7" y="10" width="384" height="15" forecolor="#4A8FC7" backcolor="#4A8FC7" uuid="77a5a131-5aa3-4094-9fa9-04f2fd2f1cd6">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
            </rectangle>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="412" y="10" width="384" height="15" forecolor="#4A8FC7" backcolor="#4A8FC7" uuid="5b5c11ca-5d00-47ab-b278-3bd60489290f"/>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="412" y="30" width="55" height="15" uuid="714e6f4c-a47d-4916-96cb-217c63fe9fe6">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.6"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.6"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.1"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.1"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Mês]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="412" y="45" width="55" height="15" uuid="dbe27dfa-8a79-4f1b-abc2-1af7f31f8cd7">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.1"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.6"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.6"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.1"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Horas]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="467" y="30" width="252" height="30" uuid="fbf525b1-4034-4953-b828-86c2f7c634b1">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <subreportParameter name="empresa">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{EMPRESA}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="dataInicial">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{dataInicial}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="dataFinal">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{dataFinal}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="parametro">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$V{multiplicadorServidorRelatorio}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{conteudoPrincipal}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="719" y="30" width="77" height="15" uuid="4bd30050-0093-4014-b5f5-37a6f1a76b63">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.6"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.1"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.1"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.6"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Tempo total]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="719" y="45" width="77" height="15" uuid="366ce86a-3346-488f-ab79-a01b1e2ec669">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <subreportParameter name="empresa">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{EMPRESA}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="dataInicial">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{dataInicial}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="dataFinal">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{dataFinal}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="parametro">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$V{multiplicadorServidorRelatorio}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <returnValue subreportVariable="valorTotalSubRelatorio" toVariable="valorTotalRelatorio"/>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{tempoTotal}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="554" y="10" width="100" height="15" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="b6d363b6-05d8-450f-9c97-1ea965339239">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font size="11" isBold="true" isItalic="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Trimestre]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="">
                <reportElement x="148" y="10" width="100" height="15" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="229eebaa-f51b-4186-938a-06c341e19f40">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{mes}.replace("January", "Janeiro").replace("February", "Fevereiro").replace("March", "Março").replace("April", "Abril").replace("May", "Maio").replace("June", "Junho").replace("July", "Julho").replace("August", "Agosto").replace("September", "Setembro").replace("October", "Outubro").replace("November", "Novembro").replace("December", "Dezembro")]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="7" y="30" width="384" height="45" uuid="7312ba1a-c833-454e-a5ed-0ac8b86a2695">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <subreportParameter name="empresa">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{EMPRESA}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="parametro">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$V{multiplicadorServidorRelatorio}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <returnValue subreportVariable="arrayChamadosSubRelatorio" toVariable="arrayChamadosRelatorio"/>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{resumoMensal}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <line>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="406" y="0" width="1" height="80" uuid="972f5ac6-a5e9-43a1-aa2f-50d10c2c1bfe">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineStyle="Dashed" lineColor="#D9D9D9"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="802" y="0" width="1" height="80" uuid="9c1090f2-20de-481a-8207-6a12b06552b3">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineStyle="Dashed" lineColor="#D9D9D9"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="406" y="0" width="397" height="1" uuid="8b17c238-66c5-4b94-8da0-0a4427b622ff">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineStyle="Dashed" lineColor="#D9D9D9"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="397" height="1" uuid="4292612f-4f93-4931-bc0f-ba79878be37c">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineStyle="Dashed" lineColor="#D9D9D9"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="397" y="0" width="1" height="80" uuid="096d778a-0de1-4415-b1ea-89ca9fba7688">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineStyle="Dashed" lineColor="#D9D9D9"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="80" uuid="0f150b56-4ef1-44d7-8776-5981c7d48c9d">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineStyle="Dashed" lineColor="#D9D9D9"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
        </band>
        <band height="272">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="496" y="45" width="103" height="15" uuid="9180e0f1-23b1-410e-8a94-0767ef08b84d">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.1"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.6"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.1"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.1"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Valor hora adicional]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="599" y="45" width="103" height="15" uuid="f5c1b9fa-4807-4954-b63b-44cb455f9782">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.1"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.1"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.1"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.6"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[java.text.NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("pt","br")).format($V{valorHoraAdicionalRelatorio})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="#0.00">
                <reportElement x="599" y="30" width="103" height="15" uuid="90d29675-0270-401a-8c81-7aa72ffc958f">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
```

Comment: Vc já "linkou" os dados do banco ao relatório? Tem como postar o código do relatório?

Comment: Vou atualizar minha pergunta com o código do relatório @Macario1983, Tive que colocar menos linhas por que atingiu o limite permitido pelo stack

Comment: Cara, pq vc n faz o tratamento de sql e população fora do relatório?

Comment: @Macario1983 mas como poderia passar isso para o relatório? Pois serão sempre N registros retornados do banco

Comment: Cara vc esta usando classes model? Pq precisa passar um objeto e na hora de montar o relatório vc usaria estes campos

Comment: @Macario1983 eu não tenho muito conhecimento em Jasper assim, o que eu estou usando agora, é passar parâmetros para meus comandos SQL's tanto dentro do relatório principal quanto nos sub relatórios, o que seria essas classes model?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78740/discussion-between-macario1983-and-r-santos).

Answer (score 0):

Esse aparenta ser um erro de classpath. O problema não acontece após a primeira execução do relatório porque, antes de executar o relatório a IDE do jasper compila os arquivos e coloca as dependências junto aos compilados.

Usa o tutorial [desse link](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-administration-guide/v561/managing-jdbc-drivers), da propria jasper soft, para reconfigurar sua conexão dentro da IDE Jasper Soft.

Para a sua aplicação, se certifica de que os jars de conexão do seu banco de dados estão no classpath de aplicação e estão acessíveis também à sua aplicação (web-inf/lib por exemplo).

Comment: Eu já adicionei os Jar's no classpath e aparentemente pelo link que você me passou eu já configurei a conexão na IDE Jasper Soft. Tanto que o erro acusa no driver do Postgresql que é algo que vem configurado de forma nativa no Jasper Studio. E eu estranhei que se eu executo o subrelatório antes do relatório principal funciona o relatório principal dai, isso já aconteceu contigo alguma vez?